# C extension: set instance variable if undefined

Tags: ruby

How to implement the following Ruby idiom in a C extension:

```
class C
  def data
    @data ||= some_method(1,2,3)
  end
end
```

I am new to writing Ruby extensions, and basically I am trying to figure out how to set an instance variable if it is not set yet.

Comment: You should break this down a little more.  Do you know how to access an instance variable from C?  Do you know how to compare it to `Qnil`?  Do you know how to set an instance variable?  Do you know how to return a value from a method?  What have you tried?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but why would you do a C extension instead of using [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki)? It would be more portable, and you wouldn't have to write C

Comment: i don't think that such an idiom is transferable. in a c extension you write C. isn't that the overall idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C extension file:

```
/* C method implementation */
static VALUE
rb_c_data(VALUE self) {
  VALUE data = rb_iv_get(self, "@data"); /* Get the @data value */

  if(!RTEST(data)) { /* Check if @data is nil or false */
    data = rb_funcall(self, rb_intern("some_method"), 3, INT2FIX(1), INT2FIX(2), INT2FIX(3));
    rb_iv_set(self, "@data", data);
  }

  return data;
}

void
Init_myextensionname() 
{
  /* Create the class definition */
  VALUE rb_cC = rb_define_class("C", rb_cObject);
  /* Bind the C method */
  rb_define_method(rb_cC, "data", rb_c_data, 0);  
}
```

Ruby C class file:

```
class C
  def some_method *args
    # whatever you want
    puts args
    42
  end
end
```